# How to minimize frequent use of Margin between elements in datagrid?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-interface

In silverlight:

I have a datagrid and in the first row there is an element in each cell. 
I want to keep a Margin of (5,0,0,0) to each element. I've set the width of column as auto and  specified the margin to each element individually.

Is there any way to specify the Margin globally (in xaml only not code behind) , so that each element would have assigned the given margin?(keeping column width Auto).

Thanks in advance for your answers!!

Searching for solution like this:

```
<Grid SetMarginForEachElement ="5,0,0,0"> 
     <element1/> 
     <element2/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must create an resource in your view like this:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="generalMargin"  Bottom="5" Left="5" Right="5" Top="5" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

After this you'll just need to bind it :

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Margin="{Binding Source={StaticResource generalMargin}}" />
</Grid>
```

Just it.
Hope it helps

Comment: Btw, you can define a Thickness in XAML like so: `<Thickness x:Key="...">5, 5, 5, 5</Thickness>` (commas optional)

Comment: @Vinicius: Again it will be same thing, i have to bind Margin property with the generalMargin for each element( other way i can say i have to write Margin again and again). i Want to avoid that thing. Searching for solution like this: <Grid PutMarginForEachElement ="5,0,0,0"> <element1\> <\Grid>

Comment: Yes you're right, but at least you'll not need to change your margin in every element if you need. The way you want i think is not possible without using code behind.